# Solution of $f(x)+g(x)=1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have two functions $f(x), g(x)$ which are defined over the real line; $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are monotonically increasing. We have also that
$$f(x)=1, \ \ \ \ \text{for} \ x=\alpha \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
and
$$g(x)=1, \ \ \ \ \text{for} \ x=\beta \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2).$$
The question is the following. Let
$$f(x)+g(x)=1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3).$$
If $g(x)$ were naught, the solution of the equation would be (1), while if $f(x)$ were naught, the solution of the equation would be (2). In general, is it possible to know the solution (or an estimation) of (3), knowing $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not necessarely a solution.

Take $f(x)=0.55+e^x$ and $g(x)=0.65+e^x$

$\forall x$, $f(x)+g(x)>1$